# Appending some text to certain message's subject in outlook's preview

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am writing a add-in for outlook 2010 using VSTO and c#.

From my add-in at run time I want to append some text to the subject of certain email messages in outlook 2010's preview pane.

A screenshot of what I am trying to achieve is below. In the screenshot please note that some of the messages have '[work email]' appended to the subject in red text. That is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: append text to outlook subject]
Is there any way of doing this either from c# or a macro?

Comment: What you trying to invent is already there and called "categorization". You may categorize e-mails with colors to give visibility.

Comment: How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. You can either modify the subject (but you won't be bale to show the string in a different color) or you can set a user defined property and configure the folder view to show the message in red if that property is present (View Settings | Conditional Formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for displaying a part of the [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) string using different colors.

A possible solution is to customize the CurrentView of the Explorer or Inspector objects. To obtain a `View` object for the view of the current `Explorer`, use `Explorer.CurrentView` instead of the `CurrentView` property of the current `Folder` object returned by `Folder.CurrentFolder`.

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property. The `XML` property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.
To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the XML property for that view.
To programmatically add a custom field to a view, use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860939.aspx) method of the `ViewFields` object. This is the recommended way to dynamically change the view over setting the `XML` property of the `View` object.